# Destructuring arrays of arrays and getting first element at the same time?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a question about array destructuring.
I have a data shaped like this :

```
const sample = [['1', '2,', '3'], ['4', '5,', '6']]
```

And I was wondering if there was a "one liner" way to get to the first element of the first array, something a little bit like this :

```
const [ first[0] ] = sample
```

Right now I'm doing something like this but I find it less "elegant" 
(I know it's not a problem at all, just trying to expand my knowledge =)

```
const [ tmp ] = sample
const first = tmp[0]
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Like... `const first = sample[0][0];`?

Comment: Maybe I should have elaborated more ! 
The data structure is actually a promise that return this array of arrays, so I would still have to store it in a var, and then access this var on a second line, but yeah, I can definitely do that ^^

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
let [[a], [b]] = sample;
console.log(a, b); // "1" "4"
```

Comment: Works like a charm =)
(actually just let [ [a] ] = sample; is enough !)

Answer (score 7):

If anyone stumbles upon this with a nested object in an array, here is an example for retrieving a parameter from the first object in a nested array:

```
const dataStructure = {
  actions: [
    {action: "foo", id: 123},
  ]
}

const { actions: [{id}] } = dataStructure

console.log(id) // output: 123
```